# At what height should underground electrical conduit enter the structure?

Tags: code-compliance

When installing an underground electrical line from the house to the garage,how high up off the ground do the access holes that go into the house & garage need to be? The purpose of this electrical line is to provide power to the inside of the garage only. Access ells will be the only thing attached to the exterior of both structures.

Comment: I live in LaPorte County,Indiana

Comment: I take it you are running this line in conduit then? If so, what type of conduit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as close to the ground as you can get them, but if you are transitioning with a junction box or your ells. You need to get it high enough to avoid getting water into it either by rain, flooding or even sprinklers. That would make it a better installation.

Good luck.